# Magento 2 Custom customer navigation in https

Tags: https, magento2

In my magento 2 site i have created a new custom navigation in customer dashboard. I have enabled https for secure urls. All the links in my account navigation are https, but my custom link is in http. How can i make it https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution In modules etc/frontend/di.xml add the below code

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfo">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="secureUrlList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="subscription" xsi:type="string">/subscription/</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

If the url has /subscription/ then it will be considered as https